# Default authenticated User nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-location

I am trying to hide elastic search behind an nginx instance. I am using the `access_by_lua_file` directive. My problem is that I want to open up access to many of the endpoints available in elastic search that do not modify documents. Right now I'm restricting access with this directive:

```
location / {
  auth_basic "Protected Elasticsearch";
  auth_basic_user_file passwords;

  access_by_lua_file '{{ nginx.lua_file_path }}';

  proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

This works great except I don't want people to be forced to provide a username for the service.

How can I do one of the following things (or maybe someone has a better way).

1. Create a similar location directive that assumes its a generic user and if the request fails, move to the location I provided above.
2. Force nginx to assume it is an authenticated user (with the lowest privs) when someone doesn't provide a user. For example, when no user is provided, we assume we've authenticated with the user `all` (which should be able to read most things, based on the lua file).

The lua file basically enumerates all of the possible requests and groups them into an "all" group/user (for everyone) and an "admin" group/user to determine if the request is acceptable or not. I would essentially want to trick nginx into assuming it was the "all" username when no username is passed in.